# Coffeescript resetCards is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, compiler-errors, coffeescript

I have been running coffeescript along with expressjs on nodejs, I am making a little script to give you 9 random playing cards (with no duplicates), I made a function resetCards to reset the cards after every display, but when I run the script it gives me:

```
TypeError: resetCards is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zunon/projects/xKoot/router.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zunon/projects/xKoot/xkoot.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
```

Here is the file router.coffee:

```
express = require 'express'
router = express.Router()

cards = []

resetCards()

router.route '/randomcard'
    .get (req, res) ->
        cardNames = []
        for i in [1..9] by 1
            cardNames[i] = createCardName()
        console.log cardNames
        res.render 'randomcard', {cardNames}
        return

createCardName = ->
    position = Math.floor Math.random() * cards.length
    cards.splice position, 1
    cards[position]

resetCards = ->
    for i in [1..13] by 1
        cards[i - 1] = "club#{i}"
        cards[i + 12] = "dmnd#{i}"
        cards[i + 25] = "hart#{i}"
        cards[i + 38] = "spad#{i}"
        if i < 3
            cards[i + 51] = "joke#{i}"  

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CoffeeScript doesn't hoist functions to the top of the scope the way JavaScript does. In JavaScript, if you say:

```
f();
function f() { }
```

it will work because the definition of `f` is hoisted to the top so that code is equivalent to:

```
function f() { }
f();
```

However, CoffeeScript only hoists the *declaration* to the top, not the *definition*. So when say this in CoffeeScript:

```
f()
f = ->
```

it looks like this in JavaScript:

```
var f;
f();
f = function() { };
```

so `f` is `undefined` when it is called and you get a `TypeError`.

The solution is to put your `resetCards()` call below the definition of `resetCards`:

```
resetCards = ->
    for i in [1..13] by 1
        cards[i - 1] = "club#{i}"
        cards[i + 12] = "dmnd#{i}"
        cards[i + 25] = "hart#{i}"
        cards[i + 38] = "spad#{i}"
        if i < 3
            cards[i + 51] = "joke#{i}"

resetCards()
```

---

Another way of looking at it is to realize that this CoffeeScript:

```
f = ->
```

is the same as this JavaScript:

```
var f;
f = function() { };
```

but that's not quite the same as:

```
function f() { }
```

There is no equivalent to `function f() { }` in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I'm used to having the functions below the $() function with jquery, I'm new to node, express, and coffeescript, so I guess I will have to get used to have the functions with the variables.